# How do require_once class.user.php

Tags: php

How to I require_once `class.user.php` to `home.php`

`class.user.php` located at `projectname/test/public`

`home.php` located at `projectname/test/public/user`

[image: image of folder]public/user

Comment: `require_once ('../class.user.php');`

Comment: this is my error msg-                                                                                Warning: require_once(class.user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\bicycleTheft\ABT\public\user\navBarLogin.php on line 3

                                                                                                                              Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'class.user.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\bicycleTheft\ABT\public\user\navBarLogin.php on line 3

Comment: You win the first price in the screenshot taking competition.

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to use absolute path with **DIR**, because inclusion works relative to uris.

so include it as `__DIR__.'./../class.user.php'`

With this the code wont break if you reframework your code and structure.

Right so assuming that you are using php version 5.5 , the DIR constants are supported. You can go with this method.

Comment: i am new not sure how?

Comment: You just need to paste the code above in your home.php script. Do you know the php version you are using?

Comment: like this require_once ('__DIR__.'./../class.user.php');

Comment: __DIR__.'./../class.user.php'

Answer (score 0):

ok here is your home.php

```
<?php
session_start();

 require_once __DIR__.'./../class.user.php'; 
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

    <head>
        <title><?php echo $row['email']; ?></title>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/homeLogin.css">


    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <?php include 'navBarLogin.php'; ?>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=col-lg-12>
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>Your bicycles are safe now</h1>
                    <h1>Click below to register your Bicycle</h1>
                    <hr>

                        <a href="bikeRegisterLogin.php" class="btn btn-default ">Register Your Bicycle Now!!</a>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: same issue-Warning: require_once(class.user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\bicycleTheft\ABT\public\user\navBarLogin.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'class.user.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\bicycleTheft\ABT\public\user\navBarLogin.php on line 3

Comment: i saw online dirname(__FILE__) how to use it?

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Do check the php version you are using.

you can get the information by creating a file, say info.php with contents as follows.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Save this and execute that file.
At the top you will find the php version as 5.5. or 7.0 something like that. post that php version string. It is just to ensure that you are running appropriate version of php.

Comment: i think 5.5 version

Comment: dont need to put requied_once

Comment: class.user.php is my db

Comment: Hasn't this been solved? okPost the code after you have made changes to your code. Lets check what have you written. I will then recommend alterations.

Comment: @Rasul write require_once before __DIR__